# Shift page up slightly. Can't get \enlargethispage*{-2\baselineskip} to work

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment

How would I shift up my 2nd page to the 1st page? There seems to be a lot of space left on the 1st page but I can't get the 2nd page to move up to the 1st page.

I tried using `\enlargethispage*{-2\baselineskip}`, and also playing around with the number, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks. My latex code is below.

[image]

```
% Cover letter using letter.sty
\documentclass{letter} % Uses 10pt
%Use \documentstyle[newcent]{letter} for New Century Schoolbook postscript font
% the following commands control the margins:
\topmargin=-1in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
\textheight=8in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\oddsidemargin=0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\textwidth=6.5in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin

\begin{document}

\enlargethispage*{-2\baselineskip}

\signature{John Doe}           % name for signature 
\longindentation=0pt                       % needed to get closing flush left
\let\raggedleft\raggedright                % needed to get date flush left


\begin{letter}{\textbf{Address Line} \\
\textbf{Address Line} \\
\textbf{Address Line} \\
Address Line, \\
Address Line, \\
Address Line, \\
Address Line}


\begin{flushleft}
{\large\bf John Doe}
\end{flushleft}
\medskip\hrule height 1pt
\begin{flushright}
\hfill House address \\
\hfill House address \\
\hfill House address \\
\hfill House address \\
\hfill House address \\
\hfill +0123456789\\
\hfill myemail@gmail.com\\

\end{flushright} 
\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page


\opening{Dear Sir/Madam,} 

Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.ragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph One.Paragraph 

Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two.  Paragraph Two. Paragraph Two.

Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three.  Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. Paragraph Three. 

Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.Thanks.

Yours sincerely,

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\closing}[1]{\par\nobreak\vspace{\parskip}%
  \stopbreaks
  \noindent
  \ifx\@empty\fromaddress\else
  \hspace*{\longindentation}\fi
  \parbox{\indentedwidth}{\raggedright
       \ignorespaces #1\\[6\medskipamount]%
       \ifx\@empty\fromsig
           \fromname
       \else \fromsig \fi\strut}%
   \par}
\makeatother
\textbf{\textit{John Doe}}

\encl{My CV.doc}                % Enclosures

\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the value of your `\textheight` to 9 inches.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use a positive number as argument to `\enlargethispage`, e.g. `\enlargethispage{4\baselineskip}`.